# Fine-uploader, fileTemplate, possible to have id?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

Is it possible to access / have Fine-uploader set the id of the uploaded file in the fileTemplate? I'm creating thumbnails of uploaded images on the server side and want to add the thumbnail of each image to the list of uploaded files. It may be possible to achive with filename but id would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Fine Uploader UI, and simply want to add these thumbnails next to the associated file element in the DOM that Fine Uploader UI creates.  If this is all true, then there is no need to add any additional attributes to the items in the templates.  Fine Uploader makes this sort of thing easy via its API.

Have a look at the `getItemByFileId` method in the [UI section of the method documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#ui).  This will return the file item in the UI, given a file ID.  So, you can do something like this:

```js
$("#uploadContainer").fineUploader()
    .on("complete", function(event, id, name, response) {
        var $fileItemInDom = $(this).fineUploader("getItemByFileId", id),
            thumbnailUrl = response.thumbnailUrl,
            image = new Image();

        image.src = thumbnailUrl;
        $(image).insertBefore($fileItemInDom);
    });
```

Notes:

- The above example assumes you have already configured an instance of Fine Uploader attached to the uploadContainer element.
- The above example assumes the name of the parameter returned in your server response that contains the thumbnail url is `thumbnailUrl`.  Change it to suit your situtation.
- You will likely need to contribute your own CSS to the above example and related HTML to fit your web application's style.

Comment: In fact, I am using the jQuery plugin, but with your answer I will probably figure out to solve my problem. Thanks! I'm sorry to have been a bit vague in my question.

Comment: I added the jQuery tag to this question and modified my answer to support the jQuery syntax.